# Piping SoX in Python - subprocess alternative?

Tags: python, audio, subprocess, sox, inter-process-communicat

I use [SoX](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/sox.1.html) in an application. The application uses it to apply various operations on audiofiles, such as trimming.

This works fine:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

kwargs = {'stdin': PIPE, 'stdout': PIPE, 'stderr': PIPE}

pipe = Popen(['sox','-t','mp3','-', 'test.mp3','trim','0','15'], **kwargs)
output, errors = pipe.communicate(input=open('test.mp3','rb').read())
if errors:
    raise RuntimeError(errors)
```

This will cause problems on large files hower, since `read()` loads the complete file to memory; which is slow and may cause the pipes' buffer to overflow. A workaround exists:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import tempfile
import uuid
import shutil
import os

kwargs = {'stdin': PIPE, 'stdout': PIPE, 'stderr': PIPE}
tmp = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), uuid.uuid1().hex + '.mp3')

pipe = Popen(['sox','test.mp3', tmp,'trim','0','15'], **kwargs)
output, errors = pipe.communicate()

if errors:
    raise RuntimeError(errors)

shutil.copy2(tmp, 'test.mp3')
os.remove(tmp)
```

So the question stands as follows: **Are there any alternatives to this approach, aside from writing a Python extension to the Sox C API?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Python wrapper for SoX already exists: [sox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox). Maybe the simplest solution is to switch to use that instead of invoking external SoX command line utilities through `subprocess`.

The following achieves what you want in your example using the `sox` package (see [documentation](http://packages.python.org/pysox/intro.html#process-audio-with-a-simple-effect)), and should work on **Linux** and **macOS** on **Python 2.7**, **3.4** and **3.5** (it might also work on Windows but I haven't been able to test because I don't have access to a Windows box):

```
>>> import sox
>>> transformer = sox.Transformer()  # create transformer 
>>> transformer.trim(0, 15)  # trim the audio between 0 and 15 seconds 
>>> transformer.build('test.mp3', 'out.mp3')  # create the output file
```

*Note: this answer used to mention the no longer maintained [`pysox`](http://packages.python.org/pysox/) package. Thanks to @erik for the tip.*

Comment: Strangely there exists [pysox Version 0.3.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox/0.3.6.alpha) from 2011 and [sox 1.2.0, a Python wrapper around SoX](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sox) from 2016. The last one’s github page is named [pysox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox)! But the last one does not work with Python 3. :-(

Comment: The maintained [python wrapper **sox**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sox) seems to work with python 3 now! And has version 1.3.2.

Comment: Any ideas how to alter the bitrate with the help of the wrapper?